# Codeigniter Unidentified Index

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, indexing

I have a function `foo` that returns an array with the below structure and what I am trying to work out is there a better way to structure my PHP as I am unsure about the indexing within the foreach as I want every `ListingId`

**Goal:**

I am wanting to write a `foreach` loop that gets the XML `<Name>` from an external XML document (Have not coded this section yet as I need to pass the `ListingID` from `foo`into the url to get the `<Name>`)

**PHP:**

```
    $test0 = $this->foo();
    $test = $test0[0]['ListingId'];
```

**Structure:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 532712629 ) [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3400- ) ) [1] => Array ( [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 532712202 ) [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3400- ) ) [2] => Array ( [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 532711566 ) [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3400- ) ) [3] => Array ( [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 532710864 ) [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3400- ) ) [4] => Array ( [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 532710271 ) [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3400- ) ) [5] => Array ( [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 532691526 ) [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3400- ) ) [6] => Array ( [ListingId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 527496168 ) [ListingCategory] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 0350-5748-3399- ) ) )
```

Comment: Can you clarify? I've reread this a couple times and not sure what you  are asking

Comment: Same here. Put some expected output. May be then it'l be clear.

Comment: @DavidNguyen I agree have changed

Comment: @itachi I have separated the question from the goal

Comment: have a look on [`php XML parser`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
foreach($this->foo() as $foo) {
   //here you can use your ListingId
   var_dump($foo['ListingId']);
}
```